I want to teach someone number theory in details starting from the beginning. How shall I start?
I want to teach my younger brother about the topic "Number Theory".
How shall I start to teach him ? He is currently at class XI.
For example, I will start with some basic concepts like Real Numbers, Natural Numbers, Whole Numbers,  Irrational Numbers, Rational Numbers, etc.
We all know that
$1)$ Natural Numbers means the set {$1,2,3,...$}
$2)$ Whole Numbers means the set {$0,1,2,...$}
Therefore Natural Numbers are subset of Whole Numbers
$3)$ Rational Numbers means only those numbers which can be expressed in the form of $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in$ Integers and $q>0$.
$4)$ Irrational Numbers means those numbers which cannot be expressed in the form of $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in$ Integers and $q>0$. Also irrational numbers have non-terminating decimal.
$5)$ Real Numbers means all those numbers which is not expressible in the form of $a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real numbers. For e.g. : $2,5,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{21},3+\sqrt{3}$
$6)$ Complex Numbers means all those numbers which are expressible in the form of $a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real numbers. For e.g. : $2+3i, 3+5i, 6-3i$
Is my explanation correct ? Also what other topics should I teach him related to number theory ? Shall I also teach him the congruence modulo topics ?
Please guide me a bit about teaching number theory to my younger brother. Please do inform me that which portions are important for a Class XI student ?

A couple things: (1) Indicators of students' age and mathematical maturity like "Class XI" are usually dependent on your location. Could you include something about your location so people can answer the question better? (2) Is the point of the question to analyze your points 1,2,3,4,5,6? #5 and #6 are very wrong in the first version of this question.

Location is India. Also how my $5$ and $6$ points are wrong ? Yes I want to analyze all the points and also some other points I want to know which I can provide knowledge to my younger brother

I've found this quite useful (although I have not taught from it): An Illustrated Theory of Numbers. "Almost 500 sharp illustrations accompany elegant proofs, from prime decomposition through quadratic reciprocity."

The Art of Problem Solving Text for this is good, and does not require a knowledgeable teacher. https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/book/intro-number-theory

To improve the quality of this question, I recommend that you give his age and what he already knows in math (since we don't know what XI means). I also recommend that you remove what you think you know of number theory, since some of it is wrong. If you use the book I recommended above, you could stay a few sections ahead of him, and help him along.

Please let me point out that you seem to misunderstand the meaning of the notion number theory.

Thank you all very much for helping me. Please edit my question to rectify the points which are wrong

I'm guessing in item 6 you meant to write "complex numbers" instead of "irrational numbers"? Since you already defined irrational numbers in item 4. (That being said, it seems like the correctness or incorrectness of your definitions is not that important to the question you're asking.)

Thank you @DavidZ. It was totally my mistake

I'm just here to second the Art of Problem Solving book suggested by Sue. I have used it before (for accelerated 12-14 year old students) with very good success. Starts simple, and builds to more complex topics including linear congruences with modular arithmetic (it might even get to the Chinese Remainder Theorem if I recall correctly).

Your item (5) is circular, using the concept of real number to define real number. In fact, the real numbers are by far the trickiest of the listed sets of numbers to define. As others have mentioned, the phrase "number theory" is usually mostly concerned with such properties of natural numbers as divisibility, primality, congruences, and the like, at least at the most elementary level, and the other listed sets of numbers wouldn't play so much of a role. (There are also analytic number theory, transcendental number theory, Diophantine approximation, and so on, where they do become central.)

It sounds like you are trying to help your brother prepare for a particular level of schooling in a particular education system, so you will need to find out what the curriculum of that system is.

Do not try to create an ad hoc course plan from first principles, from your limited experience in teaching the topic.  Instead find a textbook and use that.  No text/plan is perfect, of course.  But your goal is to have some set structure, follow it, and learn something.  Can always go back later and do more/different, etc.  But start with an established structure (i.e. a textbook) from someone who has thought through how to teach beginner number theory.  And writing a textbook tends to require much more thought and get much more quality than just asking a question on an "answers site" and reading replies.
You need a book that is suitable for high school students (i.e. does not require understanding of college math).  I would go with the easiest, funnest option available.  The objective is familiarization, interest, and not giving up.  The way to evaluate if a book meets these objectives is to read the preface, look at the table of contents and skim around in it briefly.
I did a Google search for "number theory texts for beginners" and several books came up.
Of interest, one of the autocomplete prompts was "number theory texts by Indian authors pdf".  So, you could look those over and likely find something free.  Or at least if you scan around in those, it will inform you before purchasing something.  And of course, no reason to stick to Indian writers, but maybe worth looking at to see if there is one that is in native language or somehow sings to you.  (Can still look at non-Indian authors also.)
P.s.  Your mistakes on (5) and (6) make it even more important that you not be creating the structure of a course in number theory.  You don't even know some basic definitions.  But even if you were good on the math, I would still caution against making an ad hoc plan, since you'd lack experience teaching and constructing a course/text.
